# Не получается изменять файлы docx и pdf в pytonanywhere

Tags: django, pdf, docx, pythonanywhere

Есть проект на django. На одной из страниц сайта в views.py я создаю документы docx и pdf, они наполняются необходимым текстом (текст постоянно меняется), на следующей странице уже в html я обращаюсь к этим созданным файлам и прикрепляю ссылку на них на этой странице(возможность скачивания пользователю и отображения файлов в браузере). Данные файлы сохранены в статике. Изначально в pycharm все работало. После публикации на pythonanywhere эти файлы не изменяются, ошибки никакой не выдает в коде, но и при открытии итоговых файлов, их содержимое не меняется. В чем может быть моя ошибка?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Может писалка пдф не установилась. Проверь логи